# How should I check if a given element is in the range of lists?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
A = [1,1,1,2,4]
count = []
freq = 0
#ranges = [[1, 6], [1, 6], [1, 6], [2, 7], [4, 9]]
for i in A :
        if (i >=  ranges[i][0] and i <=  ranges[i][1]):
            freq = freq + 1
            count.append(freq)
```

and my count should be [5,5,5,2,1] (since there are 5 numbers in the range of 0-5, 5 in 1-6 and 2 in 2-7 and 1 in 4-9.
However my count is returning [1,2,3,4,5]. I'm assuming it's just incrementing 1 every loop, but I can't find where the error is.

Edit: I can't iterate the ranges due to having to comply O(n), and importing dictionaries are not allowed :(

Comment: What is `time`?

Comment: You have got the logic wrong. You need to iter through ranges inside the main loop for checking. Also you need to set `freq` as 0 in each main loop.

Comment: You are never setting freq back to 0. In your code it can only increase

Comment: You surely need to iterate over the ranges at least once, otherwise -- how could you possibly know what the ranges even are?

Comment: Because before doing the ranges, I've looped over a list of integers to create ranges. So adding other loops will make it O(n+m). But I'll try around!

Comment: You seem to be adding new requirements with every edit, and alluding to additional context in the comments (which suggest that your real question involves a problem that you haven't described). Please ask a self-contained question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want simple Python looping:

```py
count = [sum([a >= r0 and a <= r1 for a in A]) for r0, r1 in ranges]
```

But, in case you are looking for something that is much faster than explicit Python loops, I'd suggest using `numpy`:

```py
A = [1,1,1,2,4]
ranges = [[1, 6], [1, 6], [1, 6], [2, 7], [4, 9]]

a = np.array(A)[:, None]
r = np.array(ranges)

((a >= r[:,0]) & (a <= r[:,1])).sum(axis=0)
```

Gives:

```
array([5, 5, 5, 2, 1])
```

**Side note**

The usual meaning of "range" in Python is left-closed and right-open: `range(a, b)` contains `a` but not `b` (as Nature intended). Your code seems to indicate that you are looking for right-closed intervals, so I mimicked that in this answer below. If you change your mind, modify `<=` into `<`.

**Speed**

```py
def fun(A, ranges):
    r = np.array(ranges)
    a = np.array(A)[:, None]
    return ((a >= r[:,0]) & (a <= r[:,1])).sum(axis=0)

n, m = 10_000, 100  # 2M comparisons
A = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=m)
ranges = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(n, 2))

d0 = %timeit -o fun(A, ranges)
# 2.25 ms ± 3.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

d1 = %timeit -o [sum([a >= r0 and a <= r1 for a in A]) for r0, r1 in ranges]
# 2.03 s ± 6.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

d1.average / d0.average
# 899x speedup
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, by passing the values in each list in `ranges` as arguments to the `range()` function.

```py
A = [1,1,1,2,4]
count = []
freq = 0
ranges = [[1, 6], [1, 6], [1, 6], [2, 7], [4, 9]]

for r in ranges :
    count.append(sum([x in range(*r) for x in A]))

print(count) # --> [5, 5, 5, 2, 1]
```

Comment: omg this works! but i'll have to work around my previous loops since right now i am already at o(n). thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is as modification of dgcodes answer:

```
from collections import Counter
A = [1,1,1,2,4]
c = Counter(A)
sc = set(c)
count = []
freq = 0
ranges = [[1, 6], [1, 6], [1, 6], [2, 7], [4, 9]]

for r in ranges :
    count.append(sum(c[i] for i in set(range(*r))&sc))

print(count) # --> [5, 5, 5, 2, 1]
```